# Множественное присваивание в Си

Tags: c

Так можно было?

```
ptr_InputFrame = (uint32_t *)((EthBaseBufferAddr = ((uint32_t)ETHERNETx) + 0x08000000) + Rhead);
```

Правильно ли я привожу аналог:

```
EthBaseBufferAddr = ((uint32_t)ETHERNETx) + 0x08000000;
ptr_InputFrame = (uint32_t *)EthBaseBufferAddr + Rhead;
```

Comment: можно, результат присваивания равен левой стороне после присваивания

Comment: только левая сторона находится под скобками и к ней прибавляется еще Rhead

Comment: Не те значения, ошибка компиляции или в чем суть вопроса?

Comment: @alexolut, во втором случае он окажется на `3 * Hread` байт дальше, чем в первом.

Comment: можете написать аналог?.. @Abyx а где должны быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t, x, y;
    x = 1;
    y = 2;
    t = ((y = y + x) + 4);
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "y = " << y << endl;
    cout << "t = " << t << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

out:

```
x = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
y = 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
t = 7
```

Comment: На самом деле код вопроса коренным образом отличается от кода ответа наличием арифметики **с указателями**. Суть в том, что добавляя к указателю N, вы увеличиваете адрес на `N * sizeof(тип, на что указывает указатель)` байт

Comment: суть вопроса в множественном присваивании.

Comment: То, что вы назвали *множественным присваиванием*, тут никакой роли не играет. А влияет приведение типа (к `uint32_t *`) перед сложением. Можете написать `(uint32_t *)(EthBaseBufferAddr + Rhead);` сумму в скобках и убедиться в этом сами.